# My reputation score is showing an incorrect value

Tags: discussion, reputation, reputation-graph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Please check below the reputation details for today:

[image]

**Question** - Why the reputation is not shown for the last two?

Comment: Please do not remove the helpful "possible duplicate" block that the Community user worked so hard to add.

Comment: Also, thanks for bringing this suspicious voting activity to the attention of the moderators. I see that all of these votes have been reversed now. Once your suspension is over, please try to obey the rules of the site.

Comment: So where does this already have an answer? Oh, at

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you have already hit the maximum reputation for a day which is 200 ( upvote,downvote ). so after that, it is not going to add any more upvote value.

For more clarification,This figure 200 does not include accepted reputation ( +15 ) or any bounty reputation. It only includes upvotes.

Answer (score 12):

There is a reputation cap. Congrats for hitting it!

You can only earn `200` rep per day from upvotes and downvotes combined. Other sources of reputation (bounties, accepted answers, etc.) are exempt.