# 4 Point Answer Upvote

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I was looking at my reputation panel on Stack Overflow today and I found the following. I got 4 points for an upvote on an answer. What causes this ?

[image]

Comment: See this [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133916/173001)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You hit the rep cap, congrats.