# Mysterious missing upvote with blank score

Tags: support, reputation, up-votes, daily-reputation-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I read the history of my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139614/how-do-i-read-the-history-of-my-reputation)

[One of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546869/how-can-i-remove-everything-from-a-remote-git-repository/11546888#11546888) yesterday got an upvote, which just made me pleased as punch on a hot summer day. However, when I went to go check my reputation to make sure my e-cred was increasing appropriately for maximum internet braggery, I came upon a startling discovery as shown here:

[image]

What's going on here and how can I prevent further reputation black holes?

Comment: You seem to have gotten the [meta-tag:daily-reputation-limit] tag on the question, so you are aware of it. So what is so surprising?

Comment: Well, I suspected it might have something to do with that; however, I've had over 325 reputation in a single day before. Also, it seemed like I was getting positive upvotes after the blank one. So, it wasn't making sense to me.

Comment: The limit only applies to votes and edits. Reputation you gain from acceptances and bounties doesn't count towards the limit.

Comment: you can visit my [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133916/173001)

Comment: I still don't understand why I was getting positive upvotes (that weren't acceptances or bounties) after the blank one.

Comment: The weird thing is that accept gives 0 rep in the screenshot (while it should give +15 according to the rule).

Comment: Nah, that's because I accepted my own answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see where you're confused. You have reputation sorted by time, which means each of those posts is sorted by the *last* event that occurred on them, even if that event didn't actually add or subtract anything. If you sort by post instead, you'll see that each of those posts above it had an additional no-rep-gain event:

[image: Compared to original screenshot]

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification. It's a little discouraging to a get a down vote for my first question on something that's not readily apparent though.

Comment: Also, why does the total show 326 in this screenshot?

Comment: Have you downvoted something? That would not show up in my public view of your history; only in yours.

Comment: +1 for freehand circles